# Which Database System to use RDBMS or NoSQL - Storing Branch Data

Tags: database, data-structures, rdbms, graph-databases, nosql

In my current system , I store Branch information in a RDBMS Database. Each Branch will have the following attributes :

1. **Latitude and Longitude**
2. Branch ID
3. Open Hours
4. Physical Address
5. **and other properties such as whether it has ATM etc**.

The current system is stored in RDBMS database. **Users input a ZIPCODE and based on this information ( Derive Lat and Long ) I pull up all branches within 15 mile radius.**

I also want the capability of Filtering through Attributes like whether the Branch has an ATM or The Branch is in a SuperMarket.

Right now I do this through SQL queries.

**Is the RDBMS the correct DB to store such information ? Should i consider NoSQL Database and of which type.**

I don't have enough Idea about No SQL database and how my data can be visualized in any other data structure format

My Branches are limited to only one State.

Interestingly , how does Google Deal with this ?

```
After researching more on this topic I have found that MOngoDB 
provides an excellent feature where in you can store the Location Details 
in a GeoJSON format. Next this can queried using their Geospatial Query     
operators. I found that after inserting around 130 objects each containing 
location and an attribute , its able to fetch Nearby objects based on 
co-ordinates provided in the query. The "With-in" miles can be dynamic. The 
calclulation to fetch objhects neary to any location within X miles 
is pretty fast ( very fast as compared to the Relational Records )
```

Comment: On what criteria this question is down voted - my simple question is there any other way this data can be represented - I don't have expertise on Other kinds of Data Structures .. give me theoretical or at least redirect to some knowledge source which it talks about such ..

Comment: @philipxy - Also after days of posting this question I had researched this question . Found about nOSQL - MongoDB - there it gives the solution about Geospatial straightaway

Comment: I just asked you two questions, have you considered answering them? Downvote mouseover: "This question does not show any research effort". For one thing, you could google your title. There are also literally dozens of textbooks online, plus presentations & courses, in which you could find basics that you could reflect in your question. (Which is essentially asking for a chapter/section from one.)

Comment: @philipxy - Edited the question .. Hope it can meet the quality

Comment: You can, also, have [GeoJSON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/store-a-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgres-with-postgis) feature with PostgreSQL which is a ORDBMS database.

Answer (score 0):

Your data sets seem to be strongly correlated, with different relations between each rows. It seems the ideal context for a RDBMS (R=relational).

Comment: Relations in the relational model are represented by tables, not associations "between" tables/rows.

Comment: What does "strongly correlated" mean? What does "relations between rows" mean? Whatever you are trying to communicate, you are not saying it.